# error The attribute "name" must be set for path "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.db2.mappings" with multiple databases

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I have a project that uses two databases. The Doctrine section of Config.yml bundle is setup as follows.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: db1
        connections:
            db1:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host2%"
                port:     "%database_port2%"
                dbname:   "%database_name2%"
                user:     "%database_user2%"
                password: "%database_password2%"
                charset:  UTF8
            db2:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: em1
        entity_managers:
            em1:
                connection: db1
                mapping:
                    FirstBundle: ~
            em2:
                connection: db2
                mappings:
                    SecondBundle: ~
```

All the parameters are setup in the parameters.yml file correctly.

whenever I run any $ php bin/console commands I get the following error

```
  [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]             
  The attribute "name" must be set for path "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.em2.mappings".
```

Are there any settings that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice your `em1` section is set to `mapping` instead of `mappings`. Also, in my working config, I set `default_entity_manager` to the connection value. So maybe try making these changes:

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: db1
    entity_managers:
        em1:
            connection: db1
            mappings:
                FirstBundle: ~
        em2:
            connection: db2
            mappings:
                SecondBundle: ~
```

That may not be the problem, but try it.